# Use class private property with MobX observable decorator

Tags: decorator, private, mobx

I am refactoring source code of my frontend application using MobX as data storage and want to use [proposed class private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields).

Unfortunatelly, private fields don't work with MobX decorators, for example, `@observable`:

```js
class Game {
  @observable.ref #levelPack;

  get levelPack() {
    return this.#levelPack;
  }
}
```

Babel transpilation fails with the following error:

> Property value expected type of string but got null

ESLint is also unhappy with it:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

I tried to use [extendObservable](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html) in constructor but it also doesn't work:

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    extendObservable(this, {
      #levelPack: null
    });
  }

  get levelPack() {
    return this.#levelPack;
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react",
    "mobx"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

My question: is it possible to use class private fields with decorators?